# Does Instagram approve client apps that want to show an public hashtag feed on their website?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am working at a agency that used to add Instagram hashtag & user feeds on websites. My old applications still work until june this year (https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/). Then they will need to be approved by Instagram to get out of sandbox mode.

I understand that we need an valid access token with: **public_content** permission scope. I read many people having their applications denied by Instagram.

When I read their permissions review (https://www.instagram.com/developer/review/) on the developer part of their site I came across this question:

> **My company is working with multiple clients, should I submit one app
>   per project?** No, we do not approve apps that are created for one-off
>   projects (e.g. a hashtag campaign, an event, a website). You should
>   use a single client_id across all your integrations.

Do they approve applications that reuses its client_id for several projects? For example if I would want to develop an application/client which whole purpose would be to show one public instagram hashtag feed on websites. Would that get approved by Instagram if I reused the applications client_id over several projects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use case is not approved. So your client will not get approved to "go live". You can still make these tag requests in Sandbox mode, but you will only get results from your last 20 posts. This short article explains [how the Instagram API works since June 1st](https://medium.com/@emersonthis/instagram-on-websites-the-new-landscape-62c91d733894#.psynexzi3).

If you can work around the 20-post restriction, you can use [this tool to manually generate an Instagram API token](https://instagramtoken.com) with the necessary `public_content` scope.

Comment: Usually we do not need more than 4 posts, so there is no need to excede the 20 post limit. So I think it will work fine in sandbox mode.

Comment: Great. Sounds like you'll be okay. But just keep in mind that the 20 post restriction is not a limit on the number of results. It's the limit on the which posts you can search. So if you haven't personally used the tag in your last 20 posts you'll get zero results.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.

I have requested public_info permission for an application simialr to yours but "DECLINED"

Try to request the permission with a good screencast video on how to use it and might be work. who knows.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, might try to make an screencast.